# Returning multiple lists of JSON from links within reoccurring JSON's

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to run/develop a script that takes a link from a JSON file, and puts that result into a list, and from that list, run a new link and repeat the process X times. In this JSON it retrns the first 25 entrees, and to get to the next 25 and so on, you need to go to the link provided in the ['paging']['next'] link

The JSON I have currently, with dummy data:

```
{'data': [{'created_time': 'time created',
   'message': 'message',
   'id': 'fake_id0'},
  {'created_time': 'created time',
   'message': 'id',
   'id': 'fake_id1'},
  {'created_time': 'time created',
   'message': 'fake message',
   'id': 'fake_id2'}],
 'paging': {'cursors': {'before': 'before code ',
   'after': 'after code'},
  'next': 'link to next JSON Script'}}
```

I know I can run the command

```
b = x['paging']['next']
```

to get to the next JSON file, I could repeat this X times, but wanted to automate this, so if i want to get 1000 of the most recent responses, I would only have to run this script once and get all the results, rather than do the link 39 times (40 x 25 = 1000 - 25(for the original script))

I have the results going into a Pandas DF with the following:

```
def JSON_dataframe(x):
    time, caption, user_and_post_id = [],[],[]
    for result in x['data']:
        time.append(result[u'created_time'])
        caption.append(result[u'message'])
        user_and_post_id.append(result[u'id'])
    df = pd.DataFrame([time, caption, user_and_post_id]).T
    df_1 = df.rename(columns={0: "Time", 1: "Caption", 2: "User_and_Post_ID"})
    return(df_1)
```

I am looking for a python script to help, or be pointed into the right direction

Comment: Are you looking for a JS or Python solution?

Comment: Looking for a python solution, I edited the post

Comment: Hi, could you show the code you use to fetch the JSON from a given link?

Comment: Laurent, why would you need that? The code I use is a basic one
"URL_request = requests.get(url)

print(URL_request.status_code)

print(URL_request)
"